# Magento connect manager/downloader not working after migrating to new server

Tags: downloader, magento-connect-manager

i recently moved my ste from one hosting company to another, then i noticed that my magento connect downloader is not working. even the Enhanced Admin Grid extension too. i replaced the downloader folder with one from a fresh download. i checked the file persmission- 755 for folder and 644 for index.php still not working, what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Path of the magento connect manager, is different on your old server. Therefore you have to contact your hosting provider and explain the situation. good luck

Comment: I have a question for you. I have a similar problem, when i go to magento admin panel >>> system >>> magento connect manager is not working at all and something strange appears on the browser. I wonder if you can help ?